# Can I use remote desktop connection on 3 screens with different resolutions (WIN 10, HyperV)

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, resolution, hyper-v

I work on remote desktop connected to local hyper-v machine using 2 Full HD screens. I'm planning to get a 3rd screen and was thinking about something with slightly better resolution. Will I be able to use all 3 screens while connected to remote machine if one of them will be 2560x1440 and 2 others 1920x1080? I'm using Win 10 Pro.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You get the same real estate on your remote environment as you have locally.